# コマンドプロンプトのnull文字判定

Tags: java

Aizu Onlineジャッジで入力された複数行の文字列に
a～zまでが何文字含まれるかを出力するプログラムを作っています。
Onlineジャッジでは動くのですが、コマンドプロンプトでプログラムを動かすと、
空行が判定できずに、プログラムの結果を取得することができません。
下のソースコードのように

```
while(true){
if(String s==null)break;
}
```

で最後の行を判定しているのですが、これは正しいやり方なのでしょうか？

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;



public class test{
    public static void main(String[] args){


        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String[] s_array;
        String s;
        StringBuffer buf=new StringBuffer();

        try{
            while(true){
        s=reader.readLine();
        if(s==null)break;
        buf.append(s);

        }
        s_array=buf.toString().split("");

        Alphabet(s_array);

        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }

    //テキストを読み込んで1行に変換したものをメソッドに代入する

    private static void Alphabet(String[] s_array){

        int[] alp=new int[26];
        Arrays.fill(alp, 0);

        for(int i=0;i<s_array.length;i++){
            s_array[i]=s_array[i].toLowerCase();

            switch(s_array[i]){

            case("a"):
                alp[0]+=1;break;
            case("b"):
                alp[1]+=1;break;
            case("c"):
                alp[2]+=1;break;
            case("d"):
                alp[3]+=1;break;
            case("e"):
                alp[4]+=1;break;
            case("f"):
                alp[5]+=1;break;
            case("g"):
                alp[6]+=1;break;
            case("h"):
                alp[7]+=1;break;
            case("i"):
                alp[8]+=1;break;
            case("j"):
                alp[9]+=1;break;
            case("k"):
                alp[10]+=1;break;
            case("l"):
                alp[11]+=1;break;
            case("m"):
                alp[12]+=1;break;
            case("n"):
                alp[13]+=1;break;
            case("o"):
                alp[14]+=1;break;
            case("p"):
                alp[15]+=1;break;
            case("q"):
                alp[16]+=1;break;
            case("r"):
                alp[17]+=1;break;
            case("s"):
                alp[18]+=1;break;
            case("t"):
                alp[19]+=1;break;
            case("u"):
                alp[20]+=1;break;
            case("v"):
                alp[21]+=1;break;
            case("w"):
                alp[22]+=1;break;
            case("x"):
                alp[23]+=1;break;
            case("y"):
                alp[24]+=1;break;
            case("z"):
                alp[25]+=1;break;
            default:break;
            }//switch

        }//for

        System.out.println("a : "+alp[0]);
        System.out.println("b : "+alp[1]);
        System.out.println("c : "+alp[2]);
        System.out.println("d : "+alp[3]);
        System.out.println("e : "+alp[4]);
        System.out.println("f : "+alp[5]);
        System.out.println("g : "+alp[6]);
        System.out.println("h : "+alp[7]);
        System.out.println("i : "+alp[8]);
        System.out.println("j : "+alp[9]);
        System.out.println("k : "+alp[10]);
        System.out.println("l : "+alp[11]);
        System.out.println("m : "+alp[12]);
        System.out.println("n : "+alp[13]);
        System.out.println("o : "+alp[14]);
        System.out.println("p : "+alp[15]);
        System.out.println("q : "+alp[16]);
        System.out.println("r : "+alp[17]);
        System.out.println("s : "+alp[18]);
        System.out.println("t : "+alp[19]);
        System.out.println("u : "+alp[20]);
        System.out.println("v : "+alp[21]);
        System.out.println("w : "+alp[22]);
        System.out.println("x : "+alp[23]);
        System.out.println("y : "+alp[24]);
        System.out.println("z : "+alp[25]);
    }//Alphabetメソッド
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ストリームの終了判定としては正しいです。

コマンドプロンプトからの入力の場合、
ストリームの終了としてＥＯＦ(End Of File)を入力する必要があります。

例えばwindows の場合<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>キーと<kbd>Z</kbd>キーを同時押しして<kbd>Enter</kbd>を押します。
(UNIX 系列の場合は<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>)